# Failed to load properties file for project

Tags: android, error-log

when creating a project at that time error will be occurred in error log.

**Message:**

```
Failed to load properties file for project 'TabActivity'
```

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
An Exception Stack Trace is not available.
```

I just try to solve these problem by deleting the `Debug keystore` placed in `c:\Users\pc\.android`.

But It couldn't solve my problem.

Anybody have an idea to solve these.Thank You.

Comment: Check my answer which worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved these issue by `Deleting the existing ADT Bundle and Extract the new ADT Bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when i was creating a new android project using eclipse but finally i got the solution.

write click on your eclipse project.

go to Build Path->Configure Build Path->select android from left side.

In Library section select and remove the existing v7 library and add again from your imported v7 project.